# position issue with nested ul's

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slide down vertical menu. My menu pushes down the other li's in the main part of the section like it's supposed to. The only problem is that the submenus move are moved to the right, and I want them lined up with their parent. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJpRL/) shows that problem.  The source code is below, but all of it is in the jsfiddle.

Thanks,
Kirie

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DEMO</title>
<style>
div{

width:180px;
}
div ul ul {
    display: none;
}

div ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}
div ul li {
    list-style:none;
    background:#F00;
    width:180px;
}
div ul ul li {
    background:blue;
    width:180px;

}
div ul ul li a{
    width:180px;
    color:white;

}
div ul ul ul li {
    background:red;
    width:180px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div>
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/SJpRL/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to your CSS:

```
ul ul{
    padding:0; /* stop children from being offset left */
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/SJpRL/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SJpRL/6/) what you are looking for.

Add a class to the sub menus and style it as folowing

```
.sub
{
    padding: 0px;
}
```